# Scraping website with Beautiful soup but getting an error

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import csv 
import pandas as pd
```

#Generate csv file

```
outfile = open('scrape.csv','w',newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
```

#List all urls

```
urls = ['https://www.rpsgroup.com/services/','https://www.rpsgroup.com']
```

#Create a blank data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Header1','Image Source', 'Alt Tag'])
```

#Html parser

```
 for i in urls:               
        Web_page = requests.get(urls)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(Web_page.content, 'html.parser')
```

#Print headings

```
h1 = soup.find_all('h1')  
print(h1.get_text())
header1 = h1.get_text()
```

#Find all images in that class

```
    image =soup.find('div',class_='organism-3-col')
    image_link = image.find_all('img')
```

#Find image and source attribute

```
for image in image_link:
    if image.has_attr('src'):
        print (image['src'])
        image_source = image('src')
        
        print (image['alt'])
        image_alt = image('alt')
    else:
        print('Source not found')
```

#Create a new data frame and add columns

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([[header1, image_source, image_link]], columns=['Header1', 'Image source', 'Image link' ])
```

#Append the previous data frame with the extracted information

```
 df= df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

#save to csv

```
df.to_csv('scrape.csv')
outfile.close()
```

Comment: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.rpsgroup.com/services/', 'https://www.rpsgroup.com']"

Comment: `Web_page = requests.get(i)`